# Xcode provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there any way to test in code about which certificate is using? (Development provisioning profile or distribution profile?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and go to the folder where you have stored the .app file.
Then write below command.

$ codesign -d -vv YOUR_APP_NAME.app/YOUR_APP_NAME

It will print information like below.

```
Executable=/Users/craig/Projects/FrenzicTouch/build/Distribution-iphoneos/Frenzic.app/Frenzic
Identifier=com.iconfactory.Frenzic
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (armv6)
...
Signature size=4331
*Authority=iPhone Distribution: The Iconfactory*
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=Nov 12, 2008 1:46:07 PM
...
```

Check Authority. If it has iPhone Distribution, its signed with distribution profile else developer.

Comment: I want to test in code, in run time. Is there any other way or any API ?